# Problems with plasma KDE desktop, Desktop Grid not working

Tags: kubuntu, kde, icons

My desktop is behaving strangely after I restarted my Kubuntu 18. I never turn off my computer, so I don't really know what might have happened. I just remember running once:

```
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt update
```

### **UPDATE**

**I've noticed that all the animations of my computer dissapeared.**

Some icons got buggy, for example the MEGA sync icon (sometimes appears with a blue folder icon behind):

[image: Buggy MEGA icon]

Also, there appears a white border around the windows when the focus is lost:

with focus:
[image]

without focus:
[image]

And lastly, the border actions of the screen and animations do not work any more, even if I reconfigure them:
[image]

Any suggestions? I am wondering if there is a way to reinstall plasma (and not dying in the attempt...)

Comment: Have you tried rebooting? Or if you don't want to do that just restarting your DE (logout and back in). When apps get updated in place it can cause weird behaviour. Are you using the `needrestart` package to restart services after library updates?

Comment: Have you tried pressing `Shift+Alt+F12`? Doing so toggles compositing which is needed for several desktop effects.

Comment: @DKBose no effect works.

Comment: @pbhj The problem appeared after a restart. Also, I haven't heard of that package, I'll look for it.

Answer (score 9):

I have the same problem. The solution for was to activate the option 'Enable compositor on startup' in 'Settings' -> 'Display and Monitors' -> 'Compositor'.
I have Kde Plasma version 5.16.3.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/R59L1BY Still facing this error over a new computer: I have enabled the option in Kubuntu 20.10, KDE Plasma 5.19.5. It didn't help